# How to use .crt file for SSH public key authentication

Tags: ssh, sftp, public-key, winscp, winscp-net

I am developing SFTP WinSCP client using C# (.NET Assembly). In my testing environment I did it by password authentication. Here are my session options:

```
// Setup session options
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions {
    Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
    HostName = "example.com",
    UserName = "user",
    Password = "mypassword",
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
};
```

But real environment don't have password for the user. Server admin provide Public Key with extension ".crt"

So using this Public Key how can I change my program (`SessionOptions`)?

Are this details enough to proceed this implementation?

Preview of crt file

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are supposed to use SFTP? The `.crt` file looks like a certificate, what is used with TLS/SSL (so possibly FTPS=FTP over TLS/SSL), not with SSH (SFTP). Also you need a private key, not public key (but `.crt` may contain both). You should generate your private key your self, you should not get it from the admin. So another confusion may be that it's certificate of the server, not your account certificate to be used for authentication.

Comment: Thank you Martin...can you give me a steps to how to do SFTP public key authentication?

Comment: No, unless you answer at least some of my question above. I haven't seen `.crt` file used for SFTP public key authentication. What does the file look like when you open it (in text editor)? Did you get any information/documentation with it from the admin regarding how to use it (even if for another client/tool)?

Comment: I add image of `.crt` file.Actually I want to SFTP client.I did it using Password authentication.But now server admin said he can't provide password and do the authentication using public key.Now I'm try to find the way, how to do this authentication. After that I can said to server admin what I need from his side

Comment: How large is the `.crt` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the extension, look and size of the the file you received, I believe it is a public key of the server in form of a certificate.

First, server's public key can be used only to verify that the server you connected to is actually the one you wanted to connect to (i.e. there's no man-in-the-middle attack ongoing).

Second, certificate format of keys is never used with SSH. It's used with TLS/SSL, so for example with FTPS (FTP over TLS/SSL), or HTTPS.

I'd say that there's some great misunderstanding between you and the server admin.

If you want more details, you should better ask on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) or [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com), as this does not look like a programming question in the end.

Comment: Thank you Martin.using winSCP is there any way to public key authentication? (without password).

Comment: Sure, use [`SessionOptions.SshPrivateKeyPath`](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions). But for that you first need to make sure you are connecting to a SSH/SFTP server at all and you need to have a private key and register public key on the server. See [Set up SSH public key authentication](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_public_key)

Comment: Martin can you give me a way to do public key authentication like this.http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh#authentication_in_ssh

Comment: Yes Martin it is SSH/SFTP.

Comment: Not sure what you ask for, I already responded in my previous comment. Did you try it? If you have a specific problem, please start a new question. This is not a discussion forum. Please read [ask].